# How to get the 2nd line of a 19GB file - python?

Tags: python, file, search, size, bigdata

There are >10 million lines in a file and the total file size is 19GB, I need to get only the 2nd line.

Getting a specific line could have been done with a loop:

```
for i,j in enumerate(open('foobar.txt')):
  if i == 1:
    print j
    break
```

Or with `linecache` (but not for large file, since it loads everything to the RAM)

```
import linecache
print linecache.getline(open('foobar.txt'),2)
```

or with `unix` commands and `os.popen`:

```
import os
infile = 'foobar.txt'
print os.popen('head -2 '+infile+'|tail -1')
```

I am exploring more options to get only the 2nd line.

- **Is there a way to read until the 2nd `\n` and then stop reading?** (this way it saves RAM space)
- **Is there a way to read until 1GB of the file and then seek for the 2nd line?**
- **What other way is there to read until the 2nd line?**

I assume the question is scalable, given that the x in the xth line that someone is small and the size of the file is >>>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the same with [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) like this:

```
import itertools
n = 1
with open('foobar.txt') as f:
    print next(itertools.islice(f, n, n+1))
```

Comment: does it load all 19GB into the RAM?

Comment: @alvas No, when you iterate over a file object, the file is read in chunks; in other words the reads are buffered.

Comment: thanks for the clarification =), is this any different from the normal iteration i use in the first code snippet?

Comment: @alvas `islice` should be faster because it counts in C code thus avoiding the `if` in Python.